# Is there a way to add your own snippets in google colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to know if I can add my personal snippets in google colaboratory.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We currently have not exposed a way to register additional snippets.

Curious if you'd be interested in personal snippets that follow you between notebooks, or notebook-specific snippets that only appear for a specific notebook.

Comment: For me, I want a global snippet library that can be use in all notebooks.

Comment: I will be interested in the ones which follow between notebooks. Like a reusable code which can be inserted easily. It will make the overall experience of creating the notebook super easy.

Comment: This is a super needed feature +1

Comment: this would be fantastic especially if they can shared with any user on that notebook

Answer (score 18):

1. Create a snippets notebook and write your snippets there (make sure to provide a searchable title in a text block to each snippet - see the screenshot below).
2. Copy the URL.

[image]

3. Then, go to `Tools > Preferences`, paste the snippets notebook URL in *Custom snippet notebook URL* and save.

[image]

Now the snippets in the snippets notebook can be searched under Code Snippets Using the title provided in the text box.

---

See the tweet by @jakevdp [here](https://twitter.com/jakevdp/status/1073251042882609152)

Comment: i can't see it in snippet filter box

Comment: i found out that i have to put a TEXT block before a CODE block to have it shown in snippet filter box